PolarDB reported space usage is different from actual usage?
I am using PolarDB 5.7 in US east zone, Control Panel told me I used 350.24GB space). But the detail table list on the right add up only to 150GB space. There is 200GB difference! Anyone might know why?
Reported space Usage vs Real Space Usage
As an end user, I can only rely on control panel. But the information provided in the control panel do not match each other.

do you have full text index? that is the known part which may not be included in the space usage statistics
